# Firebase on auth allow access to views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angular-ui-router, firebase-authentication

I have set up Google Firebase email and password authentication. I am trying to deny access to my other routes except login/registration/forgot_pass routes. **How can I limit the routes to authenticated users only?**

In this example, I want to limit access to `app.dashboard` only for logged in users. I have a `config.router.js` setup like this:

```
'use strict';

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$controllerProvider', '$compileProvider', '$filterProvider', '$provide', '$ocLazyLoadProvider', 'JS_REQUIRES',
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $controllerProvider, $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide, $ocLazyLoadProvider, jsRequires) {

    app.controller = $controllerProvider.register;
    app.directive = $compileProvider.directive;
    app.filter = $filterProvider.register;
    app.factory = $provide.factory;
    app.service = $provide.service;
    app.constant = $provide.constant;
    app.value = $provide.value;

    // LAZY MODULES

    $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
        debug: false,
        events: true,
        modules: jsRequires.modules
    });

    // APPLICATION ROUTES
    // -----------------------------------

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login/signin');
    // Set up the states
    $stateProvider.state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        templateUrl: "assets/views/app.html",
        resolve: loadSequence('modernizr', 'moment', 'angularMoment', 'uiSwitch', 'perfect-scrollbar-plugin', 'toaster', 'ngAside', 'vAccordion', 'sweet-alert', 'chartjs', 'tc.chartjs', 'oitozero.ngSweetAlert', 'chatCtrl'),
        abstract: true
    }).state('app.dashboard', {
        url: "/dashboard",
        templateUrl: "assets/views/dashboard.html",
        resolve: loadSequence('jquery-sparkline', 'dashboardCtrl'),
        title: 'Dashboard',
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            label: 'Dashboard'
        }
    })
    // Login routes

    .state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        template: '<div ui-view class="fade-in-right-big smooth"></div>',
        abstract: true
    }).state('login.signin', {
        url: '/signin',
        templateUrl: "assets/views/login_login.html",
        resolve: loadSequence('loginCtrl')

    });
    function loadSequence() {
        var _args = arguments;
        return {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', '$q',
            function ($ocLL, $q) {
                var promise = $q.when(1);
                for (var i = 0, len = _args.length; i < len; i++) {
                    promise = promiseThen(_args[i]);
                }
                return promise;

                function promiseThen(_arg) {
                    if (typeof _arg == 'function')
                        return promise.then(_arg);
                    else
                        return promise.then(function () {
                            var nowLoad = requiredData(_arg);
                            if (!nowLoad)
                                return $.error('Route resolve: Bad resource name [' + _arg + ']');
                            return $ocLL.load(nowLoad);
                        });
                }

                function requiredData(name) {
                    if (jsRequires.modules)
                        for (var m in jsRequires.modules)
                            if (jsRequires.modules[m].name && jsRequires.modules[m].name === name)
                                return jsRequires.modules[m];
                    return jsRequires.scripts && jsRequires.scripts[name];
                }
            }]
        };
    }
}]);
```